# Angular Error with VS 2017 and ASP.NET MVC Subject.d.ts File

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

I am learning to create an Angular 2 project in VS 2017 and it it the following errors during a build:

```
Error       Build:Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.    Angular2MVC D:\myProjects\Angular2MVC\Angular2MVC\Angular2MVC\node_modules\rxjs\Subject.d.ts    16
```

and

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2415  (TS) Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'. Angular2MVC (tsconfig project)  D:\myProjects\Angular2MVC\Angular2MVC\Angular2MVC\node_modules\rxjs\Subject.d.ts    16  Active
```

Here are the lines in the Subject.d.ts files:

```
    export declare class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements ISubscription {
    observers: Observer<T>[];
    closed: boolean;
    isStopped: boolean;
    hasError: boolean;
    thrownError: any;
    constructor();
    static create: Function;
    lift<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<T>;
    next(value?: T): void;
    error(err: any): void;
    complete(): void;
    unsubscribe(): void;
    protected _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription;
    asObservable(): Observable<T>;
}
```

I am fairly new to this, and I suspect that my tsConfig may be a problem.  Here it is:

```
   {
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "core-js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I have been searching a while, but without a deep knowledge, I am fishing in the dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If extends from something your constructor must be like

```
constructor(){
  super()
}
```

And you not need repeat the functions, only overrider that's functions which have a different implementation